# Prevent Tab Bar from being pushed up by keyboard in react Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385615/) in which the bottom Tab Bar is a custom component passed to React Navigation bottom Tab Navigator and I want to **prevent it from being pushed up** when the virtual keyboard pops up, which means the **opposite** to keyboardAvoidingView.

**Tab Navigator**

```
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBar={(props) => <NavBar {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
        headerShown: false,
      }}
     >
      <Tab.Screen name="Timeline" component={TimelineScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Goals" component={GoalScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notes" component={NoteScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Schedule" component={ScheduleScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

The **NavBar** component just contains a simple view container with no keyboard avoiding view anywhere

**Note:** The `tabBarHideOnKeyboard: false` works for the default tab bar but not the custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer....
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69843662/15373641) 
It just suggests wrapping the whole navigator in a fulll screen view.

Answer (score -3):

Use keyboard 'KeyboardAvoidingView'

For further detail -

https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Comment: I am asking for the view "Not to avoid" the keyboard I want to prevent it from moving up when the keyboard pops up.